# oop: on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-events

Is it possible to define a on click event inside an object (oop)?
I'm new to this.
I have been trying the following: (I simplified the code (no CSS of div etc))

```
function menu_item(menu_name){
    this.menu_name=menu_name;

    this.create = function(){
        $('body').html("<div id=" + menu_name + " />");
    };  
    
    $('#' + menu_name).on('click',function(){
        alert (menu_name);
    });
}

menu_item("test");
menu_item.create();
```

Now when I click on the div with id of the given menu_name,
I want to alert the name (as a test) but this isn't working...
is this even possible?

Comment: A couple of things: though, yes, this _can_ be done, it's far from good practice: `var foo = new menu_item('foobar'); var bar = new menu_item('foobar');` will cause issues. Also: convention dictates that constructors start with an upper-case letter, but most of all: your constructor creates an object, best to leave it at that. Constructors shouldn't mess with the DOM. An object should only bother with itself, not with what's _out there_. Lastly: you're defining functions and creating closures (probably without knowing it), specificly: `alert(menu_name);` isn't going perform as expected

Comment: thank you. i'm aware of the first problem... i will have to elements with the same id... working on it.
I can tell you what i want to accomplish with this coding:
I want to easly create mutiple menu items that move arround when clicked and then open at a certain point to display some contence.
In the original code i have more object properties:
menu_item(menu_name,menu_link,menu_target,x_offset,y_offset,x_target,y_target,how_fast,x_size,y_size)
Really a bad idea trying to do this this way?
Tips welcome since this is my first oop-like coding... 
Badankt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. However, I can't see any OOP constructor in your code - you call it as a function.

Your problem seems to be that you have no element with that id when you try to add the event listener, or a call to your `create` method overwrites it.

Use this:

```
function MenuItem(name){
    this.menu_name = name;

    this.create = function() {
        var el = $("<div id=" + menu_name + " />");
        el.on('click',function(){
            alert (menu_name);
        });
        $('body').append(el);
    };
}

var menu = new MenuItem("test");
menu.create();
```

Comment: so, to explain in my words,
the trick is to create the element (var el) so it exists and then attach the eventhandler to it (on('click',..)
I thought my code did the same, but maby the difference is that you create a variable...

Comment: No, your code did select `$('#' + menu_name)` and attached the handler when `menu_item` was called, and did *overwrite* everything when `create` was called.